# Identify this older military-style prop plane?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I was watching a show and saw this plane and I was wondering if anyone would know what it is?

[image: Plane front view]

For context, it was on the show "Arrow" and the characters were flying to a fictitious island in the North China sea. From the scene I could see 2 pilot seats and some room for maybe 2 more riders in the cockpit.

The plane seemed mid to small for such a plane and the wing has a prop on each side and then some sort of attachment near the end of each wing.

[image: Cockpit view]

Thanks for reading and for any ideas on what model it os, or where I could do some furhter research.

Regards,
-Brian

Comment: It's the same plane used in "con air"...

Comment: The "some sort of attachment near the end of each wing" are 450 gallon (1700 L) external fuel tanks.

Comment: The cockpit doesn't match the exterior shot: I'm not sure exactly what they used to film the interior, but it's not a C-123. I suspect it may be a mockup (a set - not even a simulator) but I could be wrong.

Comment: @TypeIA: Yeah, I think it might be a Boeing 737, actually. Wikipedia has [a C-123 cockpit photo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairchild_C-123_Provider#/media/File:C123KProviderCockpitCAM.jpg)

Comment: The cockpit picture shows sort of a 737 flight deck. Someone else may see more, but on first looks, the displays are configured the wrong way round - the primary flight display ("artificial horizon" and lots of other stuff) should be outboard, while the nav display ("map") should be inboard on each side. Or am I confused now?

Comment: @CptReynolds Are those not multi-function displays (MFD)?  In that case, it's pilot's choice which instrument displays on which screen.  I know some Boeings use those, but I'm not a pilot, I just recognize things from programming training sims.  It might simply be they put the artificial horizon in a prominent location because it's the one instrument that even most non-pilot audiences will immediately recognize.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman yes, that's the cockpit of a 737NG (700/800/900 series).

Comment: @jwenting My point was that if those are MFDs, it might not be incorrect to have the displays configured the way they are, since the layout is customizable to suit the tastes of the pilots.  That said, I'm not sure there's much point to having *three* artificial horizons (2 MFDs and the smaller gauge) all visible at once...

Comment: The displays on the CDUs look oddly warped. As if they're actually printed cards which are sagging in the middle. That's why I suspected it might be a prop set instead of a sim (I think it goes without saying it's not a real aircraft as it would be unnecessarily expensive and cumbersome to film in one vs. a sim or set). It does look like a 737 layout though.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman 1st is for the captain, 2nd for the copilot, 3rd is a spare. Normally the 1st and 2nd are linked to different sensor sets, so if there is a sensor problem the crew can see that quickly because the 2 are out of synch.

Comment: @TypeIA My favorite prop-error I've seen like this is when you can see the altimeter in the shot and it clearly shows that they were on the ground when it was filmed, or the throttle is all the way off or something.  (I actually took part in one such film shoot for an educational film as the copilot - on a retired C-123 with no engines - they did tell us which switches and levers to pull to make it look realistic, and we faked the gauges in post.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Absolutely! Another trope is the wildly spinning altimeter during a crash sequence. This is sometimes faked by just spinning the adjustment knob. You can see the setting in the Kollsman window spinning. For example, the Ford Tri-Motor crash scene in Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Fairchild C-123](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairchild_C-123_Provider) [Provider](https://military.wikia.org/wiki/Fairchild_C-123_Provider). Also appears in "Air America" (1990) and "Con Air" (1997).

Comment: The type also appears in "Outbreak" (1995) as the bomber that's sent to bomb Cedar Creek. I'm not sure it's the same airframe.